# Problem with xml schema elements hierarchy

Tags: xsd

What's wrong with this xml schema? It doesn't parse correctly, and I can't realize a hierarchy between cluster(element)->host(element)->Load(element).

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

  <xs:element name="cluster">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="host"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>

  <xs:element name="host">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:element ref="Load"/>
      <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>

  <xs:element name="Load">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:attribute name="usedPhisicalMemory" type="xs:integer"/>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```

Thank you, Emilio

Comment: What's a "gerarchy"? (Did you possibly mean "hierarchy"?)

Comment: Yes i did, thank you and sorry for my bad english =)

Comment: Never mind. :) I gust wanted to make sure we talk about the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To allow something like this (I corrected the typo in `"usedPhysicalMemory"`):

```
<cluster>
  <host name="foo">
    <Load usedPhysicalMemory="500" />
  </host>
  <host name="bar">
    <Load usedPhysicalMemory="500" />
  </host>
</cluster>
```

This schema would do it:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

  <xs:element name="cluster">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="host" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>

  <xs:element name="host">    
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="Load" />
      </xs:sequence>
      <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string" use="required" />
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>

  <xs:element name="Load">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:attribute name="usedPhysicalMemory" type="xs:integer" />
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>    

</xs:schema>
```

[From the MSDN on `<xs:complexType>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256067.aspx) (because [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-1/#Complex_Type_Definitions) makes my brain hurt):

> If `group`, `sequence`, `choice`, or `all` is specified, the elements must 
>   appear in the following order:
>
> 1. `group | sequence | choice | all`
> 2. `attribute | attributeGroup`
> 3. `anyAttribute`

Maybe someone else can point out the relevant section in the spec.

Answer (score 1):

In the host element, the load element cannot be a child of complexType, you must have a sequence, etc. in between.